# How to alphabetically compare two strings in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I used strcmp(x,y) in C++. Do you know how to do that in as3?

Thanks!

Comment: What dou you want to accomplish? What result? I am not familiar with strcmp function in C++.

Comment: I want a function that returns 0 if string a == b; returns 1 if a > b (alphabetically); return -1 if a < b(also alphabetically). That is how strcmp works ( string compare ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the normal operands != !== == < > <= =>

Comment: Yes alphabetical as well. You can check if a==b, a>b and a<b and return the values -1 to 1 accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

If it's a simple string compare you're after, don't bother writing one yourself.

```
var result:int = ObjectUtil.compare("stringA","stringB");
```

That achieves what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For complete Unicode strings comparing you should use the method localeCompare:

`var compare:int = a.localeCompare(b);`

It will return the alphabetical difference between the first two different letters (no matter if the different letter is the first one or any other) or zero if the strings are identical. The number will be negative if "a" comes first in the alphabet, or positive if it's "b" the first one.

So you'll have to check for:

`compare < 0`   ("a" comes first)

`compare == 0`  (identical strings)

`compare > 0`   ("b" comes first)

You should also make sure both a and b are lowercase beforehand (or both uppercase, it doesn't matter, but both should be in the same case), since localeCompare considers uppercase and lowercase to be completely different alphabets (that's because this method performs a Unicode character table comparison; the uppercase alphabet comes first).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement the function yourself. This is just an example, it would of course take a bit more work than this ...

```
 private function strComp( string1:String , string2:String ):int
 {
    var counter:int; 

    for( var i:int ; i < string1.length ; ++i )
    {
          if( string1.getCharAt(i) == string2.getCharAt(i) )
             //increment counter
          else
            break;

    }

    return counter;
 }
```